# How to get borders to collapse in IE10?

Tags: border, internet-explorer-10

Has anyone come across a solution for border collapse on tables not working in IE10?

I have tables on web sites used where needed, and they display fine in all other browsers, but Since IE 10 the borders are way to thick.

Comment: Do you have a demo showing the issue, such as a jsFiddle?

Comment: It is the page zoom that is causing the problem. Press ctrl+0 to reset the zoom to 100%. Any other zoom level (in or out) causes the borders to appear thicker. I haven't found a solution yet and there might not be one.

Comment: @Nicholas I had similar problem and it seems to be render-problem with zoom. Consider posting your comment as answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 6):

Above question may be a few months old, but today I've ran into the same problem and thought I could at least provide some possible solution, even though it's not an ideal one.

As the problem describes, using border-collapse causes a thick border in IE10, even though there are no borders that would add up. When leaving out border-collapse, the border-width remains its normal thickness. However, leaving out border-width results in space between cells.

The only possible alternative to get the desired result is to not use border-collapse at all. Instead, use 'border-spacing:0px;' to get rid of the spaces between cells and define borders very specifically.

**Example:**

This

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Would become

```
table{
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
table td{
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Like I said before: it's not ideal, but at least it would give the desired cross-browser result.

**Note:**  the problem in IE10 only occurs when using a border-width of 1px. A border-width of 1px will result in 2px when using border-collapse:collapse; in IE10. When using a higher border-width, the result will be normal.

Comment: It looks like IE10 has been fixed for this issue, but I came here looking for a solution for IE9 and found that it applies. The likelyhood of MS ever fixing IE9 is near 0 so this is very useful.