# border-collapse is not working in IE11 (Windows 10)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

Hi Html table's border is not came correctly when i run my application in IE11 (Windows 10 Machine). The css property border-collapse is not working, so my tables border is displayed as uncompleted. In chrome also its not working.

```
<table width="100%" align="center" class="tBr" id="identt" border="1" cellSpaing="0" cellpadding="2">
 <tbody>
 <tr class="bdyyow">
  <td class="bdyyow" rowspan="1"colSpan="1"> <b> EmpNo </b> </td>
 <td class="bdyyow" rowspan="1"colSpan="1"> <b> EmpName </b> </td>
  <td class="bdyyow" rowspan="1"colSpan="1"> <b> Department </b> </td>
   <td class="bdyyow" rowspan="1"colSpan="1"> <b> Designation </b> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="tb-tr1" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"> 1924 </td>
   <td class="tb-tr1" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"> Simaah </td>
   <td class="tb-tr1" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"> Production </td>
   <td class="tb-tr1" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1"> Associate</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

> CSS

```
 .tBr {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border : 1px solid black;
  }





.bdyyow {
       font-size:10px;
       border-top-width: 1px;
       border-right-width: 1px;
       border-left-width: 1px;
       border-bottom-width: 1px;
       border-right-style : solid;
       border-top-style: solid;
       border-left-style: solid;
       border-bottom-style: solid;
      }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682591/border-collapse-not-working-in-ie10

Comment: Thanks For your reply . I tried that solution but its not working.